# Scala FoldLeft: object RDD does not take type parameters

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to apply foldLeft to list of Strings as following:

```
 items.foldLeft(RDD[(String, Iterable[SomeClass])])((total, item) => total.union(fetchRDD(item))
```

where:

- item is a List[String]
- SomeClass is a simple case Class

But I receive the following exception for "RDD[(String, Iterable[SomeClass])]"-(expression in first braces of foldLeft):

"object RDD does not take type parameters"

But I receive the following exception for "RDD[(String, Iterable[WikipediaArticle])]"-(expression in first braces of foldLeft):

"object RDD does not take type parameters"  - .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass an instance of type `RDD[_]` as first parameter in `foldLeft`.

Here you are passing the object `RDD` which as the error says does not take type parameters.

You likely want to add `()` like `RDD[X]()` to create an empty RDD and use it as the zero element in the `foldLeft`.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to fold over RDDs though.. but you'll know soon I guess :)

Comment: yes, my mistake is that I pass to parameter not object, but class. Now my foldLeft works as expected. Although I was forced to find a "workaround" to get empty RDD-object from SparkContext ))